# Protractor element not optically visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

I'm a Java Script and Protractor/Selenium testing beginner.

This is what I would like to test:

*I would like to test an in-page auto scroll functionality with Protractor.*

I thought about using a - `isDisplayed()).toBe(false);` - However the element that I would be testing against will still be on the page, just not optically visible.

Is there a test to see if when the element on the top of the page is clicked, the browser does in fact move to the new position on the page?

I would be interested in either verifying that the element is not optically present in the browser window OR if the page did move to a certain location.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`isDisplayed()` is the tool for the job. It's webdriver implementation is quite complex and it would return `false` if the element is not "optically" visible.

Quote from ["Element Displayedness"](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#element-displayedness) webdriver specification:

> The visibility of a Document element is guided by what is perceptually visible to the human eye.

Pay attention to the complicated logic involved in verifying whether an element is visible or not.